# How is a unique_ptr unique?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know `unique_ptr`s cannot be copied only moved and they have no reference counting. But we can have two smart pointers that share a resource:

```
Foo* f = new Foo;
auto p1 = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(f);
auto p2 = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(f);
```

Now both of these classes share a pointer to `*f`. Also, I know this will eventually cause UB because we will be doing double delete but still: What do we really mean by a `unique_ptr` being "unique" if this is possible?

Comment: I suppose that's up to the developer to make sure never happens. It's using a naked `new`, instead of the recommended `std::make_unique` which would keep this from happening. Some practices might be better than others. They're practices because they're not enforced by the compiler.

Comment: You can even `reintrpret_cast` a pointer to `House` into a pointer to `Cat` but it would sound oddy, right?

Comment: `unique` is to distinguish it from `shared`. There is one unique owner who manages the object's lifetime.

Comment: When constructed the way it was intended, no two unique_ptr instances can manage the same object.

Comment: For what it's worth: replacing `unique_ptr` with `shared_ptr` in the example will cause exactly the same problems.  Why is it called `shared_ptr` when two instances pointing to the same object don't share ownership?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beside the fact that I do not believe that this is wanted or portable behaviour, I think that a `unique_ptr` is also a **statement** to other people working on the same project.

From [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

> std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that retains **sole ownership of an
>   object** through a pointer and destroys that object when the unique_ptr
>   goes out of scope. **No two unique_ptr instances can manage the same
>   object**.

As I understand this, the behaviour of the sample you showed is actually not wanted and should not be used at all.

For people without knowledge of the subject (aka **programming for dummies**): What the OP does is like having two girlfriends, not knowing of each other. You're fine until they find out. When they do, and they definitely will, you'll probably wish you wouldn't have played with the fire.

Answer (score 3):

To understand the terminology, you have to contrast `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`:

- the former *should* be the sole responsible for managing the resource it points to
- the latter *should* be sharing this responsibility with a set of peers

Often times, you will hear the term *ownership* to describe the responsibility of cleaning up.

Now, like many things in C++, you can attempt to subvert the system: only the *intention* is described, it's up to you to uphold your end of the bargain.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is akin to,

> How is a crescent wrench a wrench when I can use it to drive nails in
>   to the wall?

In other words, just because you can *incorrectly* use a tool to do something that shouldn't be done with it, doesn't mean it *can't* do what it was designed to do.

A `unique_ptr` is unique in the sense that you won't make copies of the pointer if you use it correctly.  It ensures that there's only one controlling object, and that the controlled object is destroyed properly when the container is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

This is about ownership semantics:

- Sole or unique ownership (e.g. `std::unique_ptr` and the old friend `std::auto_ptr`): only one pointer at a time owns an object.
- Shared ownership (e.g. `std::shared_ptr`, `boost::intrusive_ptr`, [`linked_ptr`](https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/base/memory/linked_ptr.h)): many pointers share the same object.

Answer (score 2):

It's unique because, when used correctly, it represents a unique ownership model - only one pointer gives access to, and controls the lifetime of, an object. Compare this to `shared_ptr`, which represents a shared ownership model - more than one pointer can be used to access and manage the same object.

As you point out, you can break that model by messing around with dumb pointers (either keeping hold of the one used to initialise the smart pointer, or by using `get()` or similar to bypass the ownership model). As always, it's up to the programmer to be careful not to do the wrong thing with dumb pointers. There is nothing a smart pointer can do to control the use of dumb pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Not wishing to put words in the OP's mouth, but I think the issue they may be raising might be to do with naming. Perhaps they are saying something like:

'Aaaaah! It makes no sense! The language is a work of lunacy! Lunacy, I tell you! Run! Run! Save yourselves!'.

If that's what the OP is hinting at then...

Rather than look for 'meaning' in C++ words and symbols, just try to remember their actual effects. eg 'unique' doesn't mean 'One only', even though it appears to mean exactly that, it merely has the effect of indicating that the ptr should be used in certain ways and not others. Similarly, 'Private' does not mean private, but has an effect on how something is shared. 'Static' things can move, and 'move' keeps things where they are to avoid copying them to a new location.

All you have to do is read the documentation forever, and accept the pain.
See also 'Alice Through The Looking-Glass'.